# Show popup on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a popup on the page on the selected option value.
    I need to check for the value in the select option and if it matches, the popup should be displayed. But I am unable to show the popup on the selected option changes.
    Also I want the popup shown everytime the user selects that option.
    Please advise.

```
Here is my code:
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>jQuery Popup Dialog - Click</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #overlay {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: #000;
                filter:alpha(opacity=70);
                -moz-opacity:0.7;
                -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
                opacity: 0.7;
                z-index: 100;
                display: none;
            }
            .content a {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .popup {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                display: none;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 101;
            }
            .content {
                min-width: 600px;
                width: 600px;
                min-height: 200px;
                margin: -13px;
                background: #f3f3f3;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 103;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #000;
            }
            .content p {
                clear: both;
                color: #555555;
                text-align: justify;
            }
            .content p a {
                color: #d91900;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .content .x {
                float: right;
                height: 35px;
                left: 22px;
                position: relative;
                top: -25px;
                width: 34px;
            }
            .content .x:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#DisplayShippingSpeedChoicesTD').parent().parent().parent().attr("id", "shipTable");
                $('#shipTable select').attr('id', 'shipOption');

                $('#shipOption').change(function() {
                    var value1 = ($('#shipOption option:selected').val());
                    //      alert(value1);
                    if ((value1 === "701")) {

                        //alert(value1);
                        $('.popup').show();
                    }


                });

            });







            $(function() {
                var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
                $('.close').click(function() {
                    $('.popup').hide();
                    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
                    return false;
                });

                $('.x').click(function() {
                    $('.popup').hide();
                    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
                    return false;
                });

                $('.click').click(function() {
                    overlay.show();
                    overlay.appendTo(document.body);

                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='popup'>
            <div class='content'>
                <img src='http://www.developertips.net/demos/popup-dialog/img/x.png' alt='quit' class='x' id='x' />
                 <h1>ATTENTION</h1>

                <p>We do NOT recommend using UPS GROUND for customers who do NOT live in the immediate surrounding states of Florida. Reason being is that UPS Ground is ground transport from us to you. So if you live in a state far away and select this please note that it can take up to 5 business days. If you wish to still use UPS, we recommend UPS 3 Day select as an alternative for our customers who do not live near our company.
                    <br/>
                    <br/> <a href='' class='close'>Close</a>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='container' style=" display:none;"> <a href='' class='click'><h2><b>Click Here to See Popup! </b></h2></a> 
            <br/>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I cannot see your `<select>` in your html. Were is it?

Comment: Clearly, all of the HTML markup is not included in this post.

Comment: I'mma -1 this just because the OP refuses to answer to requests for clarification and not showing all the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your HTML seems to be missing a `DisplayShippingSpeedChoicesTD` element with a nested `SELECT` statement. You're markup is a bit strange, applying `ID`s to elements after the DOM is rendered for no apparent reason other than it seems fun. Once you add this, your code works fine.

**HTML**

```
<select id="shipOption"> <!-- this element eventually becomes shipOption via some jQuery traversing -->
     <option value="101">the option is 101.</option>
     <option value="201">the option is 201.</option>
     <option value="301">the option is 301.</option>
     <option value="401">the option is 401.</option>
     <option value="501">the option is 501.</option>
     <option value="701">UPS Ground</option>
</select>
```

**script changes** Try these script changes and see what happens, I'm assuming you need some delegation that's not yet happening. Also note that you are taking chances using the `===` comparator when checking the `value1`. It is much safer to use the `==` comparator when dealing with integers or strings.

```
$(document).on('change','#shipOption',function () {
    var value1 = ($('option:selected', this).val());
    // alert(value1);
    if ((value1 === "701")) {
        // alert(value1);
        $('.popup').show();
    }
});
```